# VMWare Wrkstation 9.0 "This host does not support Intel VT-x

Tags: vmware

This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

This host does not support Intel VT-x.

For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

Please let me know how to fix this I intend to run a VM within a VM

Here is the setup

ESXi --> Windows2k8-rz ---> VMware Workstation ---> any VM

Comment: 1) "Windows2k8-rz". RZ? I assume R2?  2) Why no simple use "ESXi -> Any VM"? Much less complex. Likely much less overhead. No expensive server 2008 license needed, ...